# Using SQL to decrypt ColdFusion

Tags: sql-server, encryption, coldfusion

I have a legacy ColdFusion 9 / MSSQL website with encrypted data that I would like to migrate to another platform. The data was AES encoded with the command

```
<cfset STRING = encrypt(#STRING#, cryptKey, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "hex") />
```

I would like to use an SQL stored procedure to decrypt this data and move it to another MSSQL database but am having difficulty decoding the data. Does anyone have any idea about the best way to achieve this.

Thanks for looking

Comment: Seems the command was parsed in the original post   "cfset Additional_E = encrypt(#Additional#, cryptKey, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "hex") /"

Comment: What have you tried so far? PS: It's better to edit the question than to add extra details in comments. PPS: Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Thanks Haken, This was my first attempt, it returns a NULL...CAST(DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@Salt, STRING) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS STRING...from searches online I believe it has to do with the padding and hex setting applied in CF and I can't find an SQL equivalent

Comment: Look a bit up and you will see five word. `share` `edit` `close` `delete` and `flag`. Click on `edit` and add that extra information to the question itself. Remember to use code formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ColdFusion to decrypt the data and then move it to another database. Something like this:

```
<cfquery name="GetData" datasource="[datasource_name]">
    SELECT [uniqie_id],[column_name] 
    FROM [table]
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="GetData">
    <cfset variables.temp = Decrypt(#GetData.column_name#, [cryptKey], "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "hex")>
    <cfquery name="DecryptData" datasource="[datasource_name]">
        UPDATE [table]
        SET [column_name] = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#variables.temp#">
        WHERE [uniqie_id] = GetData.uniqie_id
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

You can also use a CLR UDF in SQL Server as stated in this post:

[AES encrypt in c# decrypt in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29904035/aes-encrypt-in-c-sharp-decrypt-in-t-sql)

Comment: CF functions cannot be applied to database columns. It does not know anything about database objects. It is simply acts as a messenger, sending SQL strings to a database and returns the results.

Comment: You are right. Updated the post to correct the code. The point was that they can use CF to decrypt the data before they move it.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions...I was trying to avoid using CF to decrypt the data base as it contains user data....in the end I decided to decrypt in CF and port the contents to a new DB